# Loading a page with un-fixed number of images which may change

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently working on a website, and got into a pretty bad position where I'm mixing javascript and php in ways that I don't think I should be (see code below for example). For the record, I'm an absolute noob in js, I usually do only backend.

What I'm trying to achieve is, get picture paths from database (done), show them on the screen (done if static) and then have a secondary container which only shows the selected image (by the user) from the list of loaded image.

Now if it were static, I could just echo with php and be done, but because it is not fixed, I have to use js which is where things get dirty. Js "doesn't know" how many pictures there are, the ids' of the tags to be able to change them and so on.

To clarify, all the pictures used in the page are loaded once in some php code at the very top of the page, and then it should just be about js handling them and moving them around and selecting them. But I think all that I need right now is a way of passing the values to js from php, and then creating the page through javascript somehow.

Is there an easy way to do what I'm saying ?

example of dirty code :

```
<script>

    var foodImages;
    <?php $i = 0; ?>

    var numberOfImages = <?php echo $count; ?>;

    for(var i=0; i< numberOfImages; i++){
        foodImages.push( <?php echo $foodImages[$i]?> );
        <?php $i ++; ?>
    }

    var selectedFood = <?php echo defaultSelected; ?>;

</script>
```

Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: you can request for the images through ajax!

Comment: You could do an ajax call to the php script when needed and use this php script to return the values to display on the page, then in your js iterate over the number of images in the response, rendering them to the page?

Comment: But wouldn't that create not needed database calls and latency? (reload images everytime)

Comment: how often are you reloading images, and what is the context? that may help with the answer

Comment: Please provide with some more details as said by Stu. You can try AngularJS where you can assign values to variable to specific or global scope

Comment: Well in theory only once, I just need to load the picture once and then javascript can play with them and move them around and such.

Comment: then there's no reason you can't load them to the dom with your php script adding a unique identifier for each, for example a class or better still a data-attribute, and use js to grab the images and manipulate them?

Comment: Yeah Stu that's pretty much what I want to do I think, I just don't know how to do that connection "adding a unique identifier for each, for example a class or better still a data-attribute, and use js to grab the images"

Answer (score 1):

So you could apply these direct to the DOM in your php script;

```
<?php
...
foreach($foodImages as $image) {
    ?><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="food-image"><?php
}
```

and then pick these up in your js;

```
<script>
...
var foodImages = document.getElementsByClassName('food-image');
```

You now have an array of DOM elements in `foodImages` js variable to use as you like?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use $count as count($array) in PHP, remove "$" to be:

```
 <?php
$numFoods=count($foodImages);
?>
    var numberOfImages = <?=$numFoods;?>;
```

Comment: oh yeah forgot to mention, that $count was initialised earlier on ! (typo in the code were I wrote it as a function

Comment: Edit the loop to correct: for(var i=0;...) lacking kwd "var".